# Dynamics CRM 365 queue view, remove '(object)' label in column

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

In my queue view, I have a global option set which is against a incident entity.
When I include it in my view, it appends the column name with a suffix "(object)".

This is happening for other option sets as well. Is there a way to remove this suffix?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is product limitation. The view column names cannot be renamed, it will load from display name of attributes and for associated entity attributes extra text will be appended within () either entity name or object.

This could be an enhancement like discussed [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/81773).

Answer (score 2):

You can only change column titles by *unsupported* means. To do so, you would do the following:

1. Open the view editor, select any column and choose *'Change Properties'*
2. Add a new Web Resource `.js` file containing basic jQuery code to select the relevant column header and change its text
3. Set the *Function Name* in the column properties window equal to the function created in your `.js` file

**Example code based on your scenario:**

```js
function changeColumnText() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("label:contains('Source')").text('Source');
    });
}
```